# Hibernate decide which fetching strategy to use at runtime

Tags: hibernate, fetch, hibernate-criteria

I have a question regarding hibernate's eager and lazy loading.
I have following setup:

```
public Person {
  int prsnId;
  Set<Preferences> preferences;
  Set<ContactDetails> contactDetails;

  //constructor

  //getters & setters
}
```

hibernate-mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="be.bene.cris2.protocol.Person" table="BENE_CUST_PERSON" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true">
        <id name="prsnId" type="int">
            <column name="PRSN_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
             <generator class="sequence">
                   <param name="sequence">CUST_PROR_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
    <set access="field" name="preferences" table="PRSN_PREF" inverse="true">
        <key column="PRSN_ID" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="Preferences" not-found="ignore"/>
    </set>
    <set access="field" name="contactDetails" table="CNTCT_DETAILS" inverse="true">
        <key column="PRSN_ID" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="ContactDetails" not-found="ignore"/>
    </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now when I execute following query, I wonder if it is possible to decide at runtime that for example the preferences should be eager loaded but the contactDetails should be lazy fetched, or sometimes not fetched at all.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
    criteria.setFirstResult(startRow)
        .setMaxResults(pageSize)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("prsnId", id))
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    ;
List<Person> personList = criteria.list();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch an association using

```
criteria.setFetchMode("preferences", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

In this case, the preferences will be fetched with the persons, in the same query, and the contact details will be fetched lazily (which means that they will only be fetched if you call a method on the set of contact details).

The problem, however, is that join fetching doesn't work with `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` because these are applied on the SQL statement directly, and are thus used to set the first and max number of rows returned by the SQL query. And a single person, if the preferences are join fetched, corresponds to multiple rows (one row per preference).